# How to access the object returned by torchaudio.info(filepath)

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, torchaudio

Upon implementing torchaudio.info on a filepath, I am getting a different return than specified in the documentation.

The code here returns `<torchaudio.backend.common.AudioMetaData object at 0x000001908CFB3B20>`

```
tempFile = os.path.join(audio_dir,'1','121007.wav')
metadata=torchaudio.info(tempFile)
print(metadata)
```

while I need a return of the following form as the documentation specifies

```
AudioMetaData(sample_rate=44100, num_frames=109368, num_channels=2, bits_per_sample=16, encoding=PCM_S)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the version issue. v0.8 did not have `__str__` method. It was added in v0.9.

https://github.com/pytorch/audio/pull/1339